# Переносимый Python скрипт

Tags: python

Как сделать переносимый Python скрипт с зависимостями на машины без интернета?

Есть:

- Несколько машин с Linux Ubuntu 14.04.1 x32
- Python 2.7.6

Нет:

- setuptools
- pip
- интернета

Цель:
собрать такой пакет, чтобы пользователь его скачивал, выполнял make, и получал в системе работающую программу.

Зависимости:

mysql-connector (использует distutils для сборки)

openpyxl (использует pip для сборки)

**upd: оказалось все проще чем я думал, mysql собрал из исходников, openpyxl установил локально с помощью pip -t, теперь пользователи могут скачать пакет и с помощью make установить все в систему. В принципе у всех убунты похожие стоят, должно завестись у всех.**

Comment: Не, ну без setuptools и pip совсем уж грустно. Вообще, есть штука для создания таких пакетов, но я забыл её название(

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то основная сложность как MySQL без интернета поставить, так как оба указанных пакета являются чистым Питоном, можно просто в один исполняемый файл упаковать (PyInstaller, cx_Freeze) и хоть с флешки его запускать.

Comment: не помещайте решение (ответ) в вопрос, используйте форму ответа ниже (чтобы например можно было комментарий по самому решению оставить, не касаясь вопроса).